# Progress Bar with Ajax JQuery and PHP for import a .csv file to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, csv

I tried to write a code for a progress bar using PHP, JQuery and HTML.
So, **I made a Ajax Request for a PHP file** and in the `success` Ajax parameter I search a `data` requested from PHP File like this..

```
success: function(data){       
    if(data == 'Error1'){
        alert("The File is not a .csv");
    }else if(data == "Error2"){
        alert("Please select a file to import!");
    }else{  
        $('#consumidor_table').html(data);
        alert("The importation has been made!");
    }
}
```

That `else` does print a Table with MySql DB lines. The PHP file read a .csv from a HTML input and insert those lines in DB.

Actually, my code to do a progress bar is it:
**Before at success parameter**

```
xhr: function(){
 var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();                      
 xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log(evt.loaded);
        console.log(evt.total); 
        console.log(percentComplete*100);
        addProgress(percentComplete*100);
    }
    });
    return xhr;
 },
```

The entire codes:
[JQuery](https://github.com/AnthonyTailer/consumidor.gov.br/blob/master/src/controller/ImportAjax.js);
[PHP URL](https://github.com/AnthonyTailer/consumidor.gov.br/blob/master/src/controller/ImportCsv.class.php)

**The Error:** When a upload a file and submit the form, the `console.log(evt.total);` and `console.log(evt.loaded);` print the same value, and them the progress bar is fully, but the Ajax continues requesting the PHP file and my table is empty yet.

So what I can do to my progress bar work with the response from PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the loading, Even I am in search of something that shows how much is complete. But I have a working code to upload CSV to Mysql.

```
<?php  
 if(!empty($_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("123.123.123.99","db_username","db_password","db_Name") or die('Unable To Connect'); 
      $output = '';  
      $allowed_ext = array("csv");  
      $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]));  
      if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))  
      {  
           $file_data = fopen($_FILES["employee_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');  
           fgetcsv($file_data);  
           while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))  
           {  
                $customerDetails = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[0]);  
                $cod = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[1]);  
                $trackingID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[2]);  
                $shipmentType = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[3]);  
                $vendorName = 'eKart';  
                $query = "  
                INSERT INTO nss_delivery  
                     (customerDetails, cod, trackingID, shipmentType, vendorName)  
                     VALUES ('$customerDetails','$cod', '$trackingID', '$shipmentType', '$vendorName')  
                ";  
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           }  
           $select = "SELECT * FROM nss_delivery ORDER BY deliveryID DESC";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select);  
           $output .= '  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
                     <tr>  
                           <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                           <th width="25%">Customer Details</th>  
                           <th width="35%">COD Amount</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Tracking ID</th>  
                           <th width="20%">ShipmentType</th>  
                           <th width="5%">Vendor Name</th> 
                     </tr>  
           ';  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["deliveryID"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["customerDetails"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["cod"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["trackingID"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["shipmentType"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["vendorName"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
           $output .= '</table>';  
           echo $output;  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error1';  
      }  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo "Error2";  
 }  
 ?>
```